# How to get URL of dropped multiple files with UIDropInteraction?

Tags: swift, file, asynchronous, drag-and-drop, uikit

I am creating a program with Swift and UIKit, that can accept and open draged and dropped files from the "File" app.

### Problem

The problem is that it can accept one file at a time, but if there are a lot of files, it may miss some. (190/250, etc.)

The possible cause is that the URL retrieval process (CompletionHandler of loadInPlaceFileRepresentation) is asynchronous, so dropInteraction(_:sessionDidEnd:) is called before all the retrieval is completed. But I can't find a way to get it right on the sessionDidEnd side.

If possible, please let me know about a better processing flow.

### Code

Finally, the openURLs method takes an array of URLs and opens them.

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession) -> UIDropProposal {
    return UIDropProposal(operation: .copy)
}

func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession) {
    self.droppedURLs.removeAll()
    for (index,item) in session.items.enumerated() {
        item.itemProvider.loadInPlaceFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: "public.item", completionHandler: { [weak self] (url:URL?, isInplaceOrCopy:Bool, error:Error? ) in
            self!.droppedURLs.append(url!)
        })
    }
}

func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidEnd session: UIDropSession) {
    if(self.droppedURLs.count > 0) {
        self.openURLs(self.droppedURLs)
    }
}
```

Also, when I simply tried to get the URL of the dropped file within the dropInteraction(_:sessionDidEnd:), I could not get the URL and got the following error.

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidEnd session: UIDropSession) {
    for item in session.items {
        item.itemProvider.loadInPlaceFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: "public.item", completionHandler: { [weak self] (url:URL?, isInplaceOrCopy:Bool, error:Error? ) in
            print(url!)
        })
    }
}
```

`Failed to open in place representation of type public.item. Error: Error Domain=NSItemProviderErrorDomain Code=-1000 "(null)"`

Thanks.

Comment: allowsSimultaneousDropSessions

Comment: @ElTomato Thank you for your precise answer. It seems solved the problem. Thanks!